# IIS Rewrite Redirect Not Working

Tags: iis

Ok I thought this was suppose to be easy, I have a number of URLS
http://www.domain.com/Home/Features

http://www.domain.com/Home/Costs

http://www.domain.com/Premier

That I was to redirect to another page (ie www.domain.com):
Such as

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^url1$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://www.domain.com/Home/Features" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I keep getting 404, what a I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a directory you will need two rules, and you really don't need aditional condition for HTTP_HOST. And if you do need it for some reason set pattern to `pattern="^domain.com$"` (https, subdomains etc.)

One rule for:

http://www.domain.com/Home/Features

and other for

http://www.domain.com/Home/Features/

so here it is:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectRule1" stopProcessing="true" >
      <match url="Home/Features/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>    
    <rule name="RedirectRule2" stopProcessing="true" >
      <match url="Home/Features(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: MM, getting 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Sorry still getting  HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: did you include rewrite and rules tags ? I tried that rewrite rule on IIS 7.5 and it works as expected

Comment: yeap <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectRule1" stopProcessing="true" > ...

Comment: Is IIS Url Rewrite extension installed on that server ?

Comment: could you try with just one rewrite, for example just for http://www.domain.com/Home/Features/ it's rule 1

Comment: huh, sorry but no idea why. I copy pasted rule from my answer and it does work on my server.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
<rule name="Features" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="Home/Features" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```